# How to save the keywords that are present in another file?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list that contains pair of keywords (`k1`, `k2`). Here's a sample:

```
print (word_pairs)
--->[('salaire', 'dépense'), ('gratuité', 'argent'), ('causesmwedemwelamwemort', 'cadres'), ('caractèresmwedumwedispositif', 'historique'), ('psychomotricienmwediplôme', 'infirmier'), ('impôtmwesurmwelesmweréunionsmwesportives', 'compensation'), ('affichage', 'affichagemweopinion'), ('délaimweprorogation', 'défaillance'), ('créancemwenotion', 'généralités')]
```

I have a text file `r_isa.txt` (205MB) that contain words that share an "isa" relationship. Here's a sample, where `\t` represents a literal tab character:

```
égalité de Parseval\tformule_0.9333\tégalité_1.0
filiation illégitime\tfiliation_1.0
Loi reconnaissant l'égalité\tloi_1.0
égalité entre les sexes\tégalité_1.0
liberté égalité fraternité\tliberté_1.0
```

This basically means, "égalité de Parseval" isa "formule" with a score of 0.9333 and isa "égalité" with a score of 1. And so go on..

I want to know based on the r_isa file, if the keyword `k1` has an hypernym relationship with the keyword `k2`, and inversely. (if `k1` is-a `k2` or `k2` is-a `k1`). On the output file, I want to save on each line the pair of words that do have the is-a relationship.

Here's what I did:

```
#Reading data as list
keywords = [line for line in open('version_final_PMI_espace.txt', encoding='utf8')]
keywords = ast.literal_eval(keywords[0])
word_pairs = []

for k,v in keywords.items():
    if v:
        word_pairs.append((k,v[0][0]))
len(list(set(word_pairs)))
 #####  


with open("r_isa.txt",encoding="utf-8") as readfile, open('Hyperonymy_file_pair.txt', 'w') as writefile:
    for line in readfile:
        firstfield = line.split('\t')[0]
        for w in word_pairs:
            if w[0]==firstfield:
                if w[1] in line: 
                    writefile.write("".join(w[0]) + "\t"+"".join(w[1]) +"\n" )
```

This doesn't give me any error, but here's my issues with it:

It takes too long: I let it run for an hour now and it doesn't stop.

This treat only one way (`if w[0]==firstfield)`, the plan is that once it's done running, I treat the other way independently by changing `w[0]` to `w[1]` (not very graceful).  Any other option?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you're looping through a 205mb file, and only storing out the w's in your word pairs (so if your word pair list has just one entry, you're still looping through 205mb!)

As memory isn't a problem here, but speed is, you could use 2 dictionary lookups; use k1/ w[0] for your key in the first dictionary (with a list of k2s as the value), and in your second dict k2 as the key with a list of k1s as the values.

Once you've prepared your dictionaries once, you can then pickle the dicts out rather than reading in a tab delimited text file. Should be a bit quicker.